# How can I start an apache storm container with custom configuration?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-storm

I'm trying to start a container with all the apache storm parts, using the dockerhub image. With the default configuration and no topology works fine.

Docker is running on a VM with Ubuntu server 18.04.2

I tried to overrride the configuration using a volume and another one to get the logs, but something is wrong. Nimbus is not starting giving as error 13

From the default configuration I just chaged theese lines

```
### ui.* configs are for the master

ui.host: 0.0.0.0

ui.port: 8081

ui.childopts: "-Xmx768m"

ui.actions.enabled: true

ui.filter: null

ui.filter.params: null

ui.users: null

ui.header.buffer.bytes: 4096

ui.http.creds.plugin: org.apache.storm.security.auth.DefaultHttpCredentialsPlugin

ui.http.x-frame-options: DENY

ui.pagination: 20
```

How can I change the UI service port and start the system properly?

Does anyone know what is error 13 in Nimbus service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the docker image's documentation you have two ways of running the container using custom configuration.
The first one is directly on the run command

```
run -d --restart always --name nimbus storm storm nimbus -c storm.zookeeper.servers='["zookeeper"]'
```

the second one is using volume (assuming that storm.yaml is on the same directory):

```
docker run -it -v $(pwd)/storm.yaml:/conf/storm.yaml storm storm nimbus
```

Comment: I solved adding to storm ui the -c option in the command line of my docker-compose and the new configuration, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I use docker-compose file for my development environment. I'm going to share the part of my compose file below which contains storm-nimbus, supervisor and storm-ui configurations statements.

```
my-nimbus:
    image: storm:1.1.0
    container_name: nimbus
    command: storm nimbus
    depends_on:
        - dependency1
        - dependency2
    links:
        - link1
        - link2
    expose:
        - "6627" 
my-supervisor:
    image: storm:1.1.0
    container_name: supervisor
    command: storm supervisor
    volumes:
     - ./storm.yaml:/conf/storm.yaml
    depends_on:
        - my-nimbus
    links:
        - my-nimbus
    expose:
     - "8999"
my-supervisor-ui:
    image: storm:1.1.0
    container_name: supervisor-ui
    command: storm ui
    depends_on:
        - my-nimbus
    links:
        - my-nimbus
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
```

You can expose and bind any port by editing ports parts. I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Can you explain a bit in the above where is your storm.yaml located while running this docker file

Comment: @ShujaAhmed For given sample my storm.yaml is located in same level with docker-compose. You can also  add  your storm.yaml to docker container with DockerFile.
Your Dockerfile may look as " FROM storm:2.2.0

ADD ./storm.yaml /conf/storm.yaml"